# How can I capture hotkeys with a windows Form closed to the System Tray

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I was wondering if I can capture specific keys while the Windows Form is minimized to system tray. And when a combination of keys are triggered, open a certain Form.

The keys I am trying to capture are: Alt + Prt Sc.

Comment: Monitoring keyboard activity globally would require you to hook into the Windows Api. I've done this in the past.  It wasn't terribly fun.  But its doable.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa

Comment: You're trying to override a Windows keyboard shortcut, not just capture it. `Alt + Prt Sc` has very specific functionality (take a window's screenshot), just like `Ctrl+C`. If you hijack it, users will be *very* angry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the winapi SetWindowsHookEx to capture hotkeys when the form is minimized.

Please find your program.cs and replace the following code with it.

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
    }

    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    private const int VK_F1 = 0x70;
    private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;
    private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc, GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            Keys number = (Keys)Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);

            if (number == Keys.PrintScreen)
            {
                if ((wParam == (IntPtr)260 && Keys.Alt == Control.ModifierKeys && number == Keys.PrintScreen))
                {
                    Form2 form = new Form2();
                    form.Show();
                }
            }


        }
        return CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
}
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: Alright, I just got home, let me test this out and send a comment with the result. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked just like intended. I added some extra modifications to the main Form I was trying to open using a hotkey, just to add some spice. Once again, thanks.